# Can I access Cassini from a remote machine?

Tags: virtualization, localhost, visual-studio

So I'm having that browser compatibility party we all have at some point in a web project and want to access my localhost Cassini instance created by VS2008 rather than having to upload to our repository/deployment environment to check when IE6/7 are playing nice.

Can anyone tell me if I can access the VS Cassini from another machine? And if so what I have to do to get it working? If not what options do I?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: If I remember correctly the build of Cassini that ships with Visual Studio is hard coded to bind to the loopback device so you wouldn't be able to access it remotely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had previously thought you could adjust the settings of Cassini to listen for remote connections. However this is only the case if you are building Cassini your self (for use in your application etc) which is what I had used it for previously. The version of Cassini built into the Visual Studio debugger is only accessible locally and that is hard coded.

Your best bet is to install IIS on your local PC and use that.

Answer (score 2):

NO.

According to MSDN, you can't access it from another machine.

**What are some known functionality limitations of the Cassini Web server?**

- It can host only one ASP.NET application per port.
- It does not support HTTPS.
- It does not support authentication.
- It responds only to localhost requests.

see this [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893391)

Answer (score 0):

YES. (Sorry for reviving, but I feel my answer will add value)

If you don't mind traffic redirection, see my Stack Overflow answer to my own question, as I had this problem, and a need for debugging external requests without actually using a remote debugger.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13625361/561545